# Enable hebrew on mysql database [wamp]

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert hebrew values to my MySQL database, but the output is only strange chars, or question marks(???? ???) or empty rectangles ▯▯▯▯ .

I've tried to change the collation and the charset to utf8, but it dont helped so much.

When I use the command "show variables like 'char%' :
everything is utf8 (except character_set_filesystem --> binary of course)

By the way, I am using WAMP Server.
How can I fix it and use hebrew on mysql database?

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [mysqli charset](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_set_charset.asp) prior to insert or select, i.e.:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```

and set your table fields to :

Charset Set: `utf8`
Collation: `utf8_general_ci`

---

**Update** based on you comment:

Your string is `json` encoded to decode it use:

```
$string = '{"name":"\u05d1\u05d9\u05d2 \u05d1\u05d5\u05e8\u05d2\u05e8"}';
print_r( json_decode($string));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => ביג בורגר
)
```

Comment: {"name":"\u05d1\u05d9\u05d2 \u05d1\u05d5\u05e8\u05d2\u05e8"}
this is the output now. its still not in hebrew. what is this characters? 

and the character set of the table is utf8 already

Comment: What do you mean by `{"name":"\u05d1\u05d9\u05d2 \u05d1\u05d5\u05e8\u05d2\u05e8"} ` ?

Comment: u05d1\u05d9\u05d2 \u05d1\u05d5\u05e8\u05d2\u05e8 this is the output that should be written in hebrew like that : דוגמא